# How to delete a point with known coordinates in python?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I was wondering if there is a piece of code that does the opposite that setGeometry does and removes a point if there is one at x and y coordinates?

Comment: Are you looking for a method that deletes the feature or that just removes the geometry from the feature at this point (as you're asking for the opposite of setGeometry)